# append tuples to array in groups python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to append tuples to my array in groups. The number of groups or the number of tuples in each group is unknown.

I'm aware there should be a very simple answer for this, but my mind is grasped on swift, which takes care of this issue for me.

This is my issue, I need to be able to do this:

```
array = []
array[0].append([1, 2]) # error because there isn't a '0' index
array[0].append([7, 2])
array[0].append([89, -5])
array[1].append([2, 3])
```

so I don't get the wrong kind of responses of why I'm not doing it another way I made a simple program to illustrate the point of why I need it to work like this.

```
def get_data(index, array):
    # loop for an un-determined number of times, calculates differently depending on the index
    one_or_more = 4
    for i in range(0, one_or_more):
        # do some calculations depending on index, which should differ for each loop
        data1 = index * 3 + i
        data2 = index * 4 + i
        array.append([data1, data2])


def main():

    array = []
    array_index = 0
    some_num = "110, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 130, 131, 323, 324, 325, 326, 340, 341, 342, 343".strip().split(", ")
    for i in some_num:
        get_data(int(i), array[array_index]) # error here with 'array[array_index]', because I can't index array with '0' because it's not initialized yet
        array_index += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":main()
```

Comment: Is there some reason why you don't want to use a list comprehension for this?

Comment: every time I call the function I need the tuples that it appends to be in a new group. @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, can you give me an example of how 'list comprehension' would fix this issue? I do not know how many times the function will be called so I don't want to initialize the python array

Comment: To further explain, the 'calculations' I indicated above include SQL queries, and the indexes indicate part of the path of the websites I am querying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value at a given index is being over written. So, an array is not a suitable data structure for your task. I would use a defaultdict.

```
from collections import defaultdict

key_lists = defaultdict(list)
key_lists[0].append([1,2])
key_lists[0].append([89, -5])
key_lists[1].append([2, 3])

print(key_lists)
print(key_lists[0])

one_or_more = 4

for i in range(0, one_or_more):
    data1 = index * 3 + i
    data2 = index * 4 + i
    key_lists[i].append([data1, data2]
```

Comment: thank you for your help, this is just what I was looking for

Comment: The versatility and performance of defaultdict makes it invaluable for practically any task. The collections library has other great data structures. For instance, if order is important checkout collections.ordereddict.